# Swap lists and sequences

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I'm looking for a function which does the following:

```
ListSequenceSwap[{6, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, {2, 2}, {4}}]
```

{{6}, 1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, 2, 2, 4}

```
ListSequenceSwap[{6, {0}}]
```

{{6}, 0}

```
ListSequenceSwap[{6, {0}, {1}}]
```

{{6}, 0, 1}

```
ListSequenceSwap[{6, 7, {0}, {1}}]
```

{{6, 7}, 0, 1}

The solution I found is so convoluted that I would prefer not to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

testcases = {
  {6, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, {2, 2}, {4}}
  , {6, {0}}
  , {6, {0}, {1}}
  , {6, 7, {0}, {1}}
  }

SequenceReplace[#, {{a__?NumericQ} :> {a}, {x_List} :> 
     Sequence @@ x }] & /@ testcases
```

> {{{6}, 1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, 2, 2, 4}, {{6}, 0}, {{6}, 0, 1}, {{6, 7}, 0,
> 1}}

Answer (score 4):

```
lsSwap = Replace[SplitBy[#, ListQ], a : {__List} :> Splice@Flatten[a], {1}]&
```

***Examples:***

```
lsSwap[{6, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, {2, 2}, {4}}]
```

> ```
> {{6}, 1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, 2, 2, 4}
> ```

```
lsSwap[{6, {0}}]
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0}
> ```

```
lsSwap[{6, {0}, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0, 1}
> ```

```
lsSwap[{6, 7, {0}, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{6, 7}, 0, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
spliceDeepLists[a : {__List}] := Splice@Flatten@a
spliceDeepLists[a_] := a;

swapLS = Map[spliceDeepLists]@SplitBy[#, ListQ] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
swapLS[{6, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, {2, 2}, {4}}]
```

> ```
> {{6}, 1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, 2, 2, 4}
> ```

```
swapLS[{6, {0}}]
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0}
> ```

```
swapLS[{6, {0}, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0, 1}
> ```

```
swapLS[{6, 7, {0}, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{6, 7}, 0, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
step[{a___}, b_List] := {a, Splice @ b}
step[{a___, b_List}, c_] := {a, Append[b, c]}
step[{a___}, b_] := {a, {b}}

sequenceListSwap = Fold[step, {}, #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
sequenceListSwap @{6, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, {2, 2}, {4}}
```

> ```
> {{6}, 1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, 2, 2, 4}
> ```

```
sequenceListSwap @ {6, {0}}
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0}
> ```

```
sequenceListSwap @ {6, {0}, {1}}
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0, 1}
> ```

```
sequenceListSwap @ {6, 7, {0}, {1}}
```

> ```
> {{6, 7}, 0, 1}
> ```

Comment: (+1) Nice way to use `Fold`!

Answer (score 1):

```
listSequenceSwap = SequenceReplace[a : {__Splice} :> (# & @@@ a)] @* Map[Splice];
```

***Examples:***

```
listSequenceSwap @ {6, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, {2, 2}, {4}}
```

> ```
> {{6}, 1, 2, 3, {4, 5}, 2, 2, 4}
> ```

```
listSequenceSwap @ {6, {0}}
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0}
> ```

```
listSequenceSwap @ {6, {0}, {1}}
```

> ```
> {{6}, 0, 1}
> ```

```
listSequenceSwap @ {6, 7, {0}, {1}}
```

> ```
> {{6, 7}, 0, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SplitBy` and `Cases`:

```
lst = {6, 7, {0}, {1}, 4, 5, 8, {2, 2}, {4}};
Cases[SplitBy[lst, ListQ], x_ :> If[VectorQ[x], x, Splice@Flatten@x]]

(*{{6, 7}, 0, 1, {4, 5, 8}, 2, 2, 4}*)
```

Also, in a more programmatic way:

```
 ListSequenceSwap[list_List] := 
 Module[{element, flist, len, i, temp}, flist = {};
 len = Length[list];
 i = 1;
 While[i <= len, element = list[[i]];
 If[NumericQ[element], temp = {element};
 While[i < len && NumericQ[list[[i + 1]]], 
 AppendTo[temp, list[[i + 1]]]; i++];
 AppendTo[flist, temp]; i++, 
 If[Head[element] === List, flist = Join[flist, element], 
 AppendTo[flist, {element}]]; i++]]; flist]
```

Testing `ListSequenceSwap`:

```
ListSequenceSwap[lst]

(*{{6, 7}, 0, 1, {4, 5, 8}, 2, 2, 4}*)
```